# How can we formalize $\mathrm{Subset}$, the "category" of all subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Suppose $X$ is an object of $\mathrm{Set}$. Then we can define a category of subsets of $X$ in the usual way; objects are equivalence classes of monomorphisms $f : A \rightarrow X,$ etc. Now this construction is great for some purposes - it means, for example, that the intersection of two subsets of $X$ can be defined as the categorial product. However it is not so good for other purposes. In particular: suppose $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $A$ and $B$ are respective subsets. Then intuitively, the notion of a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a perfectly reasonable concept. However, according to our previous construction, since $A$ and $B$ belong to different categories, thus the notion of an arrow $A \rightarrow B$ makes no sense.

How can we formalize a category $\mathrm{Subset}$ of all subsets, such that

- Given a subset $A$, its absolute complement $A^c$ is well-defined as unique.
- If $A$ and $B$ are subsets, then an arrow $A \rightarrow B$ is just a function in the intuitive sense of the word.

---

*Discussion*. Obviously $\mathrm{Subset}$ will be equivalent to $\mathrm{Set}$. The interesting thing about $\mathrm{Subset}$ is that it has extra structure. In particular, each object $A$ of $\mathrm{Subset}$ is cut from a larger context $X \supseteq A$. Lets denote this context $k(A)$. So $k$ is a function $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathrm{Subset}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Ob}(\mathrm{Subset}),$ and really $k$ ought to be idempotent. We also require a distinguished injection $i(A) : A \rightarrow k(A)$ for all objects $A$. This tells us how to view $A$ as a subset of its context $k(A)$.

However, I don't know how to proceed with formalizing the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define the category $\mathbf{SubSet}$, such that:
$$
Ob(\mathbf{SubSet})=\{(X,A)\in Ob(\mathbf{Set})\times Ob(\mathbf{Set})|\;A\subset X\};
$$
$$
hom_{\mathbf{SubSet}}((X,A),(Y,B))=hom_{\mathbf{Set}}(A,B),
$$
with obvious composition and identities. Of course, $\mathbf{SubSet}$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$. Also you can define the mapping $k\colon Ob(\mathbf{SubSet})\to Ob(\mathbf{SubSet})$, such that $k(X,A)=(X,X)$. Of course, $k$ is idempotent(but it doesn't define a functor $\mathbf{SubSet}\to\mathbf{SubSet}$!).

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Alternatively, one can define $\hom ((X,A) , (Y,B)) = \{f \colon X \to Y : f(A) \subset B\}$. That way, $k$ has a natural extension to the arrows, making it a functor.

Comment: @Pece +1. Let me just note: such category is not equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to pursue this idea seriously, please do take a look at *fibrations*.  Chapter 1 of [Bart Jacobs's book](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/bookseries/0049237X/141/supp/C) would be a good start.